# Freestyle - unwanted silouhette lines

Tags: modeling, freestyle

I'm trying Freestyle for the first time, and I'm using a combination of edgemarks, borders and silhouette on a low poly character. I really want to keep the silhouette parameter to show some details (like the fingers), but it also gives me some unwanted lines. I tried changing the edge detection settings, but with no results. Does anyone have an idea on how to get rid of these, or does it have to be removed manually? [image]